# How to check VNCserver connection log?

Tags: vnc

I run the vncserver using vnc4server.

How can I view a history of IP addresses that have connected to vncserver and how long they stay connect in VNCserver?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed myself
i installed tightvncserver instead vnc4server
and log file include IP now

thank!